# Can not get adb log output using plugin.shell("logcat") anymore

Tags: google-chrome-arc

I used “plugin.shell(‘logcat’)” directly in the JavaScript console(chrome://inspect#apps) to get adb log informations before.
But recently, after several times of upgrade, whenever I tap the command, it always prompts "Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]:”resolved”, [[PromiseValue]]:Object}” and no log is displayed.
I have tried to get adb log from ui_log in chrome://system, but failed, the log I write in the code is not displayed either.

I found this problem quite a few days ago and thought it would be fixed be Google.
However, it is still there util now.

My test device information
Chrome OS : version 45.0.2454.15 dev
ARC : 45.5021.433.5

My question is : How can I get adb log now? Or should I use some other method to get adb log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known regression issue and under investigation now.

Note : logcat is still available in Chrome 44 on stable channel.

Comment: Is there a bug entry tracking this?